# how to replace all special characters with DOT (.) R

Tags: r

Hi i Have data frame need to replace all special characters with "."

```
df
variabe
name:A-B c
name/A-B-c
name-A/B:c

i have tried 
df$variable =  gsub("-", ".", df$variable)
df$variable =  gsub(":", ".", df$variable)
```

..
Is there any function / modification to do in a single step

```
o/p
variabe
name.A.B.c
name.A.B.c
name.A.B.c
```

Thanks

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(365)`

Comment: @jogo more like `fortune(14)` imo: a little look at `?regex` can help

Comment: but sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `[[:punct:]]` to match any punctuation characters and replace with `.`

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]+", ".", df$variabe)
```

Comment: you don't need the `+` and depending on the characters to replace, maybe just `gsub("[:-)]", ".", df$variable)`

Comment: @Cath If there are patterns like `"A::B_` and want to replace with a single `.`

Comment: ok but it is not sure whether OP would like to replace that with a single dot or 2 though